# Conditional assignment in typescript like kotlin when

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am beginning in learning typescript and it's language features. One thing I miss is something like the when expression or a conditional assignment. Something like

```
val languange = "DE"

val test = when(languange) {
   "DE" -> "HALLO"
   "EN" -> "HELLO"
   else -> "NONE"
}
```

The only way I found to implement this in typescript was:

```
const language = "DE"

var description: String;

if (language == "DE") {
   description = "HALLO"
} else if (language == "EN") {
   description = "HELLO"
}
```

Ain't there a more handy way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object (or Map) is a possibility:

```
const language = "DE" as const;

const descriptionsByLanguage = {
  DE: 'HALLO',
  EN: 'HELLO',
  // etc
};
const description = descriptionsByLanguage[language];
```

Comment: Does the language have to be a const? Or is it just optional?

Comment: It makes the typings easier. It can also be typed as just a `string`, but then you'll need to check whether the property exists on the object first, or TypeScript won't let you do `descriptionsByLanguage[language]` - either that, or change the type of the object / Map to map strings to strings.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error "Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type."

Comment: Are you sure you did `const language = "DE" as const;` as in the answer? If you don't do that, then like I said in the comment, you'll have to check whether the property exists on the object first.

Comment: Or sorry I forgot those. But I cant write language as const, because then it says "A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals." I get my language value from a firebase function and  therefore cant cast it. What would be the work around?

Comment: Then, like I said, you need to check whether the property exists in the object first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14664748 either that, or change the type of the object to map strings to strings, instead of `'DE' | 'EN'` to values