# Filter an array of objects according to the name of the key in the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I want to filter based on the name of the key for those objects. In this particular case I know that there will be one key/value pair for each element in the array.

Assume an array that looks like this:

```
let dataArray = [
  {
    "name": "David" 
  },
  {
    "location": "New York"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jenna"
  }
]
```

What I want to end up with is just an array where the `key` is 'name':

```
[
  {
    name: "David" 
  },
  {
    name: "Jenna"
  }
]
```

I've tried various ways of doing this using the `filter` method, such as this:

```
const namesArr = dataArr.filter(i => i[key] === 'name');
```

But none seem to produce the correct result.

Comment: `dataArray.filter(o => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, 'name'))`

Comment: What do you mean by “the” key? What if these objects have multiple keys or no keys?

Comment: In this case I know what data I will be getting, and there will only ever be one key/value pair for each object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript), specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/49899370/13762301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in` operator to check if a property exists on the object:

```js
const dataArray = [{"name":"David"},{"location":"New York"},{"name":"Jenna"}];

// name exists on the object
console.log(dataArray.filter(item => 'name' in item));

// or location doesn't exist on the object
console.log(dataArray.filter(item => !('location' in item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to filter on a particular key being present, see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```js
dataArr.filter(obj => 'name' in obj)
```

Only checking `obj.name` would exclude objects where 'name' field is  `false` or `null` or `undefined`, even if the property is present on the object.

Comment: This one is really succinct. Nice!

Comment: It is, just beware that e.g. `'hasOwnProperty' in {} === true`

Comment: As well as all other properties in its prototype chain

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `object.hasOwnProperty('name')` that returns a boolean indicating whether object has a property name

```js
let dataArray = [
  {
    "name": "David" 
  },
  {
    "location": "New York"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jenna"
  }
]

const filtered = dataArray.filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('name'));

console.log(filtered);
```

another option is to use the `in` operator:

```js
let dataArray = [
  {
    "name": "David" 
  },
  {
    "location": "New York"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jenna"
  }
]

const filtered = dataArray.filter(x => 'name' in x);

console.log(filtered);
```