# How to check for the existence of dynamic property inside an object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
const result = {
    "MEN": [],
    "WOMEN": [],
    "KIDS TEMP": [
        "BCDEFHJJJJJJ34EEE234",
        "ABCDEFGHIJKL12345678"
    ]
}
const result = {
    "MEN": [],
    "WOMEN": [],
    "CHILDREN TEMP": [
        "BCDEFHJJJJJJ34EEE234",
        "ABCDEFGHIJKL12345678"
    ]
}
```

I have an object `result` like above. Sometimes, it may have `KIDS TEMP` property and sometimes `CHILDREN TEMP`. Since this property has spaces, I cannot use dot operator to fetch these properties.
I want to create a flag if either of `KIDS TEMP` or `CHILDREN TEMP` exist.
I tried below:-

```
const part = 'KIDS TEMP' || 'CHILDREN TEMP';
    let check;
    if (result) {
      check = !!(result?.MEN.length !== 0 || result[part].length !== 0);
    }
```

But the above code breaks when I receive `CHILDREN TEMP` saying that it cannot read length of undefined.
How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to do both checks separately. `const part = 'KIDS TEMP' || 'CHILDREN TEMP';` will not magically run two checks later, it will simply store `'KIDS TEMP'` in `part`. What you can do is use an array: `const parts = ['KIDS TEMP', 'CHILDREN TEMP']` then use `parts.some(part => result[part] && result[part].length)`

Comment: [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)

Comment: `I cannot use dot operator to fetch these properties`, you can access the property even if it has spaces or reserved keywords in the key. You just need to use the square brackets in place of the dot: `result['CHILDREN TEMP']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` returns the property names of an object. You can check like this, if an object possesses a certain property:

```js
const result = {
    "MEN": [],
    "WOMEN": [],
    "KIDS TEMP": [
        "BCDEFHJJJJJJ34EEE234",
        "ABCDEFGHIJKL12345678"
    ]
}

console.log(Object.keys(result).includes("KIDS TEMP"));
console.log(Object.keys(result).includes("CHILDREN TEMP"));
```

If you want to test, if a certain attribute exists, and in case it exists, contains a non-empty array, you can test it like this:

```js
const result = {
    "MEN": [],
    "WOMEN": [],
    "KIDS TEMP": [
        "BCDEFHJJJJJJ34EEE234",
        "ABCDEFGHIJKL12345678"
    ]
}

console.log(result["KIDS TEMP"]?.length > 0);
console.log(result["CHILDREN TEMP"]?.length > 0);
```

The main problem with your code is that `const part = string1 || string2` always evaluates to `string1`, which is not what you intend to do.

Comment: It evaluates to `string1`

Comment: Correct, @ChrisG

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object's method [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) it will return `true/false` depends on if property exists in object or not.

```js
const result = {
    "MEN": [],
    "WOMEN": [],
    "KIDS TEMP": [
        "BCDEFHJJJJJJ34EEE234",
        "ABCDEFGHIJKL12345678"
    ]
}

console.log(result.hasOwnProperty('KIDS TEMP'),result.hasOwnProperty('CHILDREN TEMP'));
```