# Test if object contains property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check for an object property, but I can't understand why the second option returns false. Could anyone explain? Also, are there any other better ways to check properties?

```js
let question = {
    category: 'test'
}

console.log(question.hasOwnProperty('category')); // true
```

this wont work

```
let question = {
    category: 'test'
}

console.log(question.hasOwnProperty(question.category)); // false
```

Comment: It returns false because you don't have a property with the name `test`. *(not my downvote)* Your first code block shows correctly asking if the object has a `category` property. Your second asks if it has a property with a name that you're getting from `question.category`, which is the string `test`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)

Comment: if ('category' in question) { ....

Comment: This is just a typo, it should be taken down.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
    foo: 'bar',
};

// Check if an object has a certain key somewhere
console.log('foo' in obj);
console.log(!!obj['foo']);
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo'))

// Check if an object has a certain value somewhere
console.log(Object.values(obj).includes('bar'));
```

Answer (score -1):

In this line:

`question.hasOwnProperty(question.category)`

The part `question.category` returns 'test' and you haven't 'test' like property, just leave it like that:

`question.hasOwnProperty(category)`

Answer (score -1):

You can also check property using:

```
'category' in question
```