# Check for a key inside In array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the best way to check whether an object key is present inside multiple objects present in an array which will provide a boolean as output
`[{alert:hi},{alert:bye},{}]`

From the above example basically what I am trying to achieve is if any one object is missing the alert object key the output should be as false or anything

Comment: The answers seem to try and reinvent [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135448) which has been on the site for more than a dozen years? Note the top answer by John Resig (author of jQuery): "*I'm really confused by the answers that have been given - most of them are just outright incorrect. Of course you can have object properties that have undefined, null, or false values.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your array with [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Something like this:

```js
const objects = [{alert:'hi'},{alert:'bye'},{}];
const every = objects.every(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('alert'));
console.log(every);
```

Comment: This will not shortcut if a mismatch is found?

Comment: `{alert: ""}` will be counted as a failure

Comment: Note this wont work with `{alert: false}` either

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method and check if at least one element is `undefined`

```js
const isAlertMissing = (array) => array.some(elem => elem.alert === undefined)

const objs1 = [{alert: "foo"},{alert: "foo"},{}]
const objs2 = [{alert: "foo"},{alert: "foo"}]

console.log(isAlertMissing(objs1))
console.log(isAlertMissing(objs2))
```

Comment: `{alert: undefined}` means *the key is present* but the value of it is set to `undefined`. That's different to `{}` where the key is *not* present.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `every` to check all items and `some` with `Object.keys` for finding a key in the inner objects.

```js
const data = [{alert:"hi"},{alert:"bye"},{}]
const result = data.every(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => key === "alert"));

console.log(result) //false
```

**EDIT**

`some` with `Object.keys` is kind of roundabout, so we can use `hasOwnProperty` instead.

```js
const data = [{alert:"hi"},{alert:"bye"},{}]
const result = data.every(item => item.hasOwnProperty("alert"));

console.log(result) //false
```

Comment: `Object.key()` is extremely roundabout way to check for a key. Moreover, it only works on own keys which rarely matters but might still be a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

`Array#some` will succeed as soon a match is found, making it more efficient than `Array#every`.

```js
const test = (data, propName) => 
  !(data.some((el) => !el.hasOwnProperty(propName)))

const data1 = [ {alert:'hi'}, {alert:'bye'}, {}]
const data2 = [ {alert:'hi'}, {alert:'bye'}]

console.log(test(data1, 'alert')) // false
console.log(test(data2, 'alert')) // true
```

Or:

```js
const test = (data, propName) => {  
  for(let el of data) {
    if(!el.hasOwnProperty(propName)) 
      return false 
  }

  return true
}

const data1 = [ {alert:'hi'}, {alert:'bye'}, {}]
const data2 = [ {alert:'hi'}, {alert:'bye'}]

console.log(test(data1, 'alert')) // false
console.log(test(data2, 'alert')) // true
```