# find min from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have list of statuses where not started is the minimum , followed by submitted and last is complete.

So if we apply the logic on the data since there are 2 status on the current array of object below which are "Not Started" and  "Submitted" so the function should return Not Started because not started is the min.

If there is only 1 item in an array then get the only status as a result.

How do we filter the array of objects and  get the min based on the order in statuses array. Thanks for any idea.

#currentCode

```
  getMin(id:number , key:string) {
    
    let data = [
      {
          "id": 14,
          "status": "Submitted",
  
      },
      {
          "id": 15,
          "status": "Not Started",
      }
  ]

    let min = Math.min(...data.map(item => item.status));

    console.log('result' , min)

  }
```

#order of statuses

```
  statuses: any[] = [
    { viewValue: 'Not Started', value: 1 },
    { viewValue: 'Submitted', value: 2 },
    { viewValue: 'Complete', value: 3 },
  ]
```

#sample array of objects  - result Not Started

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 14,
        "status": "Submitted",

    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "status": "Not Started",
    }
]
```

#sample array of objects  - result Submitted

```
  data = [
        {
            "id": 14,
            "status": "Submitted",
    
        },
         {
            "id": 17,
            "status": "Complete",
        }
    ]
```

#sample array of objects  - result Complete , since there is only 1 get the only status

```
  data = [
         {
            "id": 17,
            "status": "Complete",
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up the status from `data` in your `statuses` array.

```js
const data = [
      {
          "id": 14,
          "status": "Submitted",

      },
       {
          "id": 17,
          "status": "Complete",
      }
  ];

const statuses = [
    { viewValue: 'Not Started', value: 1 },
    { viewValue: 'Submitted', value: 2 },
    { viewValue: 'Complete', value: 3 },
  ]

let min = Math.min(...data.map(item => statuses.find(st => st.viewValue === item.status).value));
let minStatus = statuses.find(st => st.value === min).viewValue;

console.log(minStatus);
```

Comment: it should display the viewValue Sir not the value

Comment: So for example on your code the output is Submitted not 2

Comment: Right, so you'd need to look up the value 2 again in the statuses array.  I'll update the code.

Comment: Thank you Sir , appreciated

Comment: how do we handle for example there is status in an object where value is null ? , it would cause error on the function

Comment: I just have one question why is that  filteredCategory.map is not a function ? https://imgur.com/a/nhZy0pE

Comment: re "status" field null or undefined, you could filter the data array first to eliminate these.  re "filteredCategory.map" - filteredCategory?  That's neither in your question nor my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution is to simply sort the array by `statuses` value, which then gives you access to the complete ordering, and the entire object for each position. Here first mapping the `statuses` array to an object keyed by `viewValue` to directly access status values.

```js
const data = [
  { "id": 14, "status": "Submitted", },
  { "id": 17, "status": "Complete", },
  { "id": 15, "status": "Not Started", },
  { "id": 15, "status": null, }
];

const statuses = [
  { viewValue: 'Not Started', value: 1 },
  { viewValue: 'Submitted', value: 2 },
  { viewValue: 'Complete', value: 3 },
];
const statusMap = Object.fromEntries(statuses
  .map(({ viewValue, value }) => [viewValue, value])
);

const sorted = data
  .filter(d => Object.hasOwn(statusMap, d.status))
  .sort((a, b) => statusMap[a.status] - statusMap[b.status]);

const min = sorted.at(0);
const max = sorted.at(-1);

console.log('min:', min.status);
console.log('max:', max.status);

// or the complete objects
console.log({ min, max })
```

##### Edit

Added a `filter()` call before sorting to remove datum that don't have a status that appears in `statusMap` using [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn). This also makes the original spread redundant since `filter()` returns a new array thus avoiding mutation of the original `data` array with the `sort()` call.

Comment: how do we handle for example there is status in an object where value is null ? , it would cause error on the function

Comment: Do you not want `null` statuses included? If so just filter them out.

Comment: yes , it should not include empty or null status

Comment: error Property 'hasOwn' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2022' or later.ts(2550)

Comment: sounds like you're transpiling to older js. You can use `statusMap.hasOwnProperty(d.status)` or `d.status in statusMap` but you might want to output more modern js from TS. see: [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)