# Count Of a specific key if present inside a object of array [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

Hi guys iam trying to find the count of a specified field if its present inside a object of array
For example

```
[{name:'Linus',rate:'23'},{name:'Sebastin'},{name:'Alex',rate:''}]
```

what iam trying to achieve is count the number of key 'rate' inside the object

iam expecting a output like

```
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the input data and count the number of times the key occurs in one of the objects:

```js
data = [{name:'Linus',rate:'23'},{name:'Sebastin'},{name:'Alex',rate:''}] 

const countKeys = (data, key) => data.reduce((acc, o) => acc + (key in o), 0)

console.log(countKeys(data, 'rate'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [{name:'Linus',rate:'23'},{name:'Sebastin'},{name:'Alex',rate:''}];
var count = 0;
var key ='rate';
data.forEach(d =>{
  if(d.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    count++;
   }
});
console.log(count);
```

A reference for you [how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property-in-javascript)