# Use JSON.Stringify() to check if object is empty in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have this component in my react js application:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "luo",
      amount: ""
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(errors), "f");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("firstName", { required: true })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

When i click on submit i get the next issue: `Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value`, this happens because of using JSON stringify. 
 Question : Why i get this issue in my code  and how to use JSON.stringify and to get rid of the issue? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ts-forked-wfzjyr?file=/src/index.tsx:0-776

Comment: The `errors` object has a nested `ref` property that points to the HTMLElement object that is invalid. That object has a property `__reactInternalInstance...` that stores an object, which has a property called `stateNode` which points to the same HTMLElement reference, so you have a cycle. Why do you want to check if your object is empty in the first place? Perhaps you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` and then check the length of the array you get back as an alternative to stringifying, but it's not clear if you actually need to do that depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) explains this error quite well:

> The JavaScript exception "cyclic object value" occurs when object references were found in JSON. JSON.stringify() doesn't try to solve them and fails accordingly.

In other words, `data` has some property that references itself hence a cycle. So turning it into a string naively would result an never ending string. Thus `JSON.stringify` throws an error if it detects this to be the case.

The docs also outline a good solution but warn that it does cause data loss by ignoring the cyclical value:

```js
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};
```

Then to call it in your code:

```js
JSON.stringify(errors, getCircularReplacer());
```

From your code, it looks like you think you need to call `JSON.stringify` in order to use it, e.g. with `console.log`. This is not necessary for `console.log` and the console will allow you inspect cyclical objects. This is also true for `alert` but the output is not useful e.g. `[object Object]`. However from what I can see, there's no strong reason to use `alert` over `console.log` here.

But why even use `JSON.stringify` if your requirement is to check if it's empty?

From what I can see, when the input field is empty, `onSubmit` is not called but `errors` is populated with property `firstName`. So to check if you have errors for `firstName`:

```js
Object.hasOwn(error, 'firstName');
```

See also [How do I check if an object has a specific property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/885922)