# JavaScript .sort() undefined value always should be "earlier"

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort an array of objects by multiple fields (3-4 in my case). Some values of object could be **undefined** and those values must be always "earlier" in sorting (ascending and descending). In my case everything works when sorting is descending, but in case of ascending values which are **undefined** are always in the bottom. Type of those values is always a string and I could call only .sort() method nothing before it and after. My code looks like this:

```
[{id: "1", label: "Z", code: "Z"}, 
 {id: "1", code: "A"},
 {id: "2", label: "A",},
 {id: "3", label: "A", code: "A"}]
     .sort((a,b) => {
          return a.id.localeCompare(b.id)
             || a.label.localeCompare(b.label)
             || a.code.localeCompare(b.code)
     );
```

Comment: If you want to check if a property exists in JS, the see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/136411/4688321

Comment: Based on what do you want to sort? What is the exact use case?

Comment: So what's the expected order for your example. The simplest would probably be, checking for `undefined` before using `localeCompare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your own comparison function. `0` means they're the same, a positive number means `b` should come first, a negative number means `a` should come first.

```js
const localeCompareUndefined = (a, b, locales, options) => {
  if (a === undefined && b === undefined) return 0;
  else if (b === undefined) return 1;
  else if (a === undefined) return -1;
  else return a.localeCompare(b, locales, options);
}

const data = [{id: "1", label: "Z", code: "Z"}, 
 {id: "1", code: "A"},
 {id: "2", label: "A",},
 {id: "3", label: "A", code: "A"}]
.sort((a, b) => {
  return localeCompareUndefined(a.id, b.id) ||
    localeCompareUndefined(a.label, b.label) ||
    localeCompareUndefined(a.code, b.code)
});

console.log(data);
```